# No_data_found exception is propagating to outer block also?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ora-01400, ora-01403

In my code i am entering the salary which is not available in employees table and then again inserting duplicate employee_id in primary key column of employee table in exception block where i am handling no data found exception but i do not why `No data found` exception  in the end also?

OUTPUT coming:

```
Enter some other sal
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCOTT"."EMPLOYEES"."LAST_NAME")
ORA-01403: no data found  --This should not come according to logic
```

This is the code:

```
DECLARE
v_sal number:=&p_sal;
v_num number;
BEGIN
   BEGIN
            select salary INTO v_num from employees where salary=v_sal;
   EXCEPTION
           WHEN no_data_found THEN
                   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Enter some other sal');

           INSERT INTO employees (employee_id)values(100) ;
   END;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlerrm);
END;
```

Comment: Technically your original exception wasn't handled, it threw another exception.  This seems to me expected behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour is that errors hurled in the EXCEPTIONS block get concatenated to SQLERRM, and hence propagated upwards.  I grant you [it is not documented](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/13_elems50.htm) but we can clearly see it here:

```
SQL> declare
  2      v_sal t23.sal%type := 230;
  3      l_num t23.sal%type;
  4  begin
  5      begin
  6          begin
  7              select sal into l_num
  8              from t23 where sal = v_sal;
  9          exception
 10              when no_data_found then
 11                  dbms_output.put_line('inner exception::'||sqlerrm);
 12                  insert into t23  values (99, 'MR KNOX', v_sal);
 13          end;
 14      exception
 15          when dup_val_on_index then
 16              dbms_output.put_line('middle exception::'||sqlerrm);
 17              insert into t23 (id, sal) values (99, v_sal);
 18      end;
 19  exception
 20      when others then
 21          dbms_output.put_line('outer exception::'||sqlerrm);
 22  end;
 23  /
inner exception::ORA-01403: no data found
middle exception::ORA-00001: unique constraint (APC.T23_PK) violated
ORA-01403: no data found
outer exception::ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("APC"."T23"."LAST_NAME")
ORA-00001: unique constraint (APC.T23_PK) violated
ORA-01403: no data found

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Note: if there is a nested exception block which successfully handles the thrown exception it is not concatenated to SQLERRM.  That is, the SQLERRM consists of a stack of unsucessfully handled exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

In your exception block you try to insert into `employees`, but do not set the column `last_name`, which is not `NULL`-able.

> ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCOTT"."EMPLOYEES"."LAST_NAME")

The `ORA-01403: no data found` is part of the stack-trace, caused by your failed select.

---

You can either define `DEFAULT` values for all not-nullable columns or change your insert:

```
INSERT INTO employees (employee_id, last_name, ...) Values (100, 'Scott', ...);
```